# I can only read voltages <3V with my multimeter, why?

Tags: voltage, multimeter

Some time ago I bought a multimeter from a not so known brand (I think): The LOMVUM T 18D.
Below is the official product page:

http://www.lomvum.com/pid18291854/T18A-B-C-D-E-Intelligent-Multimeter-6000-Count-Digital-High-precision-Automatic-Multi-function-Portable-Anti-burn-Digital-Table.htm

Today I thought it was not working at all, but after some tests I found out only the voltage readings are incorrect, and only when above 3.0 V. When I test voltages below 3.0 voltages it works perfect.

My assumption is that it is related to the auto range feature that doesn't work for voltages anymore, but I'm wondering if this is true (and can it be fixed?). Has anybody seen this kind of malfunction before?

Comment: Yeah, probably the auto-ranging. Might be a comparator that got fried?

Comment: @Polynomial I haven't opened it yet (too less time, but I will do after the weekend). But just checked, it seems it's glued, not meant to be opened, maybe for a reason :-)

Comment: My guess would be that there's a wheatstone bridge in there with the instrumentation amplifier sitting across it, and a comparator that checks the measured voltage against a reference in order to signal "range up", and another comparator with another reference to "range down". That'll be driving the gain on a PGA for the frontend, or something equivalent. So anything in that path (voltage reference, comparator, upstream logic, PGA) could be damaged and produce this faulty behaviour.

Comment: use an external voltage divider until you can replace it

Comment: Test with another voltmeter - you do have more than one don't you?

Comment: @Polynomial Thanks for the info, I cannot open the device, however, I will add an  update, but possibly not close  the question also because of your info that might be useful to others.

Comment: @jsotola I can use another multimeter.

Comment: @SolarMike Yes I have plenty but I like this one.  However, it is not broken (going to add an answer).

Answer (score 2):

I feel quite stupid. I guess with this multimeter I never read voltages before (or only under 3 V).

What I did was selecting the wrong mode.
When the Continuity/Diode/Resistance (RED circled) button is selected with the FUNC/Hz button Voltage can be selected and I thought that was for DC currents.

[image]

However, I checked that the V button is for both AC and DC (see https://www.electrical-symbols.com/electric-electronic-symbols/electric-current-symbols.htm, universal equipment logo). I thought that logo was for AC only. See the symbol below.

[image]

I couldn't find a decent manual for this multimeter, but I will find a similar multimeter to find out the features for the Continuity/Diode/Resistance (RED circled) button.

With the Continuity/Diode/Resistance (RED circled) button it seems voltage can be measured, but just until 3.0 V. Above 3.0 V it shows .0L (V).

Comment: Seen that symbol (wavy line on top of straight line) for years to mean AC & DC...

Comment: @SolarMike you are right (it means AC & DC, or DC / AC, or do I miss something in your remark?).

Comment: Oh, it's always AC/DC ...